# How can we increase the performance for Cosmos graph on azure

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Do we have a feature wise optimization somewhere for azure cosmos db graph .
For an instance can we use parallel processing, Caches, Indexes for cosmos db to increase the performance . If so how ?
Could not find enough documentation on that , please help.

Comment: Hey Varun, this question can be kind of hard to answer on Stack Overflow as it can be a bit vague and it will change over time. Would you mind emailing AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com instead? The Gremlin team can answer your questions in more detail w/ some back and forth.

Comment: Sure Chris . Thanks